# Dynamically include files (components) and dynamically inject those components

Tags: reactive-programming, reactjs

Looking around the next I could not find the answer: How do I dynamicly include a file, based on prop change per say: here some sudo code to intrastate what I'm trying to do!

```
class Test extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = { componentIncluded: false }

    includeFile() {
        require(this.props.componetFileDir) // e.g. ./file/dir/comp.js
        this.setState({ componentIncluded: true });

    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="card">
                <button onClick={this.includeFile}> Load File </button>
                { this.state.componentIncluded && 
                    <this.state.customComponent />
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

so `this.props.componetFileDir` has access to the file dir, but I need to dynamically include it, and can't really do require() as its seems to running before the action `onClick` get called. Any help would be great.

Comment: anyhow, `Button` component will be imported, why don't you want to do simple import and then manage the behavior of imported component?

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: I got it working using `require.resolve` as `System.import` is not supported by stable build of `webpack` and did not want to include `system.js` for one function.

Answer (score 1):

Em, Your code looks a bit wrong to me. So I created a separate demo for dynamic inject components.

While in different situation you can use different React lifecycle functions to inject your component. Like componentWillReceiveProps or componentWillUpdate.

```
componentDidMount() {
    // dynamically inject a Button component.
    System.import('../../../components/Button')
      .then((component) => {
        // update the state to render the component.
        this.setState({
          component: component.default,
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    let Button = null;
    if (this.state.component !== null) {
      Button = this.state.component;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        { this.state.component !== null ? <Button>OK</Button> : false }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

After you edited your code, it should be something similar to below:

```
class Test extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = { customComponent: null }
        this.includeFile = this.includeFile.bind(this);
    }

    includeFile() {
      System.import(this.props.componetFileDir)
        .then((component) => {
          this.setState({ customComponent: component.default });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="card">
                <button onClick={this.includeFile}> Load File </button>
                { 
                    this.state.customComponent
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: that all make sence but im getting `System is not defined`, where is system located and how do I import it ?

Comment: that link you have provided is 404. Can you point me to the correct direction. oh and btw i'm using babel.

Comment: Sorry. I'm using my phone to type. https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs

Comment: You can try upgrade you webpack to webpack 2. @Kivylius